# Table TagHelper for an IEnumerable Model (without using Reflection)

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a table tag helper that can parse columns and rows from the given model automatically.

This is how it should (theoretically be used):

```
<table for="@Model">

</table>
```

and this should automatically show column names and the rows.

Generating column names wasn't that difficult since I'm passing the model

```
[HtmlTargetElement("table", Attributes = "for")]
public class DataTableTagHelper :TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        foreach (var item in For.Metadata.ElementMetadata.Properties)
        {
            // generate html for theader using item.Name
        }
    }
}
```

But getting the values of the model isn't as easy.

Is there a way to get the values of those properties?

I'm trying to avoid reflection, because I don't think generating HTML code though reflection with every request is a good idea.

Comment: What is the type of your Model? Can you post the class of your Model.

Comment: it should be generic for tables, so anything that implements IEnumrable, and I'm lopping over the properties of the model
so you can assume IEnumrable<SomeClass> is the model, and I'm looping over all properties of SomeClass

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Your `Model` implements `IEnumerable`. Is that right?

Comment: correct, and the class inside is whatever

Comment: For the rendered HTML table, do you want the column names to come from the `whatever` property names?

Comment: yes, and this is exactly done from the code in the question (item.Name), but I dunno how to get the value

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, prop.PropertyGetter is the key for it but instead of passing the model, you need to get the enumerator and pass each object sparely, thank you for you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get the property's value by passing the model to its property's `PropertyGetter`.

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    foreach (var prop in For.Metadata.Properties)
    {
        var propertyName = prop.Name;
        var propertyValue = prop.PropertyGetter(For.Model);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If the model implements `IEnumerable`, then we need to pass each item to its `PropertyGetter`.

```
public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    foreach (var item in For.Model as IEnumerable)
    {
        foreach (var prop in For.Metadata.ElementMetadata.Properties)
        {
            var name = prop.Name;
            var value = prop.PropertyGetter(item);
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help
but not that I'm trying to get the values for the ElementMetadata which is the type of the object inside the list
(For.Metadata.ElementMetadata.Properties) Not For.Metadata.Properties

using your code is firing cast exceptions

Comment: yes this is exactly how I solved it (relying on your first answer), there is one small edition though, TagHelpers don't support generics and the type can't be known at this point, so just edit your answer as IEnumrable (the none generic interface) and everything else is good, I will accept your answer ;)